The bullet point of the list items doesn't align properly with the text. Why is that?
To clarify this, I'm attaching a picture. What I'm referring to is that the bullet point is not perfectly centered, it is slightly shifted upward.

Here is the code I wrote for both the HTML and CSS. To be honest, it doesn't deviate much from the default behavior.


*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 1.8em;
}

ul > li {
  padding: .1em 0;
}

li::marker {
  color: #1f93a1;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

ul > li > p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>List Items</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>First Item</li>
      <li>Second Item</li>
      <ul>
        <li>Sub-item</li>
        <li>Sub-item</li>
      </ul>
      <li>Third Item</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>



I appreciate any suggestions.

The :marker is centered in the li, the text is not. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LYKzWxV - This is standard, there is usually space above and below text glyphs depending on the font. These are not always equal.

Probably easier to use custom marker with a proper pseudo-element and align with flexbox.

They're misaligned because of the larger font size on the ::marker. If you try removing that, you'll see that the bullet point will align with the text.
If you want a larger font size for the marker, you'll have to tweak the line height to match with the text.
This article may be of help: https://www.svgbackgrounds.com/custom-css-bullets-with-marker/
